# difference between setTimeout in javascript and $timeout service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, angular-services

Iam new to angular framework.Here is my scenario where, I want to change my $scope.variable after a period of time so i used javascript `setTimeout` method.

```
$scope.variable = 'Previous';

setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.variable='NEXT';
},3000);
```

This code doesn't work for me. I used `$apply()` to make this code work.

Later I came to know that angular itself has a $timeout service which does the same work.

```
$scope.variable = 'Previous';

$timeout(function () {
  $scope.variable = 'NEXT';
}, 2000);
```

How can i compare performance of `$timeout` service with javascript `setTimeout`??

Why we should use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`??

Please give me some examples and reasons to use it, which shows the performance.

Thanks :)

Comment: The performance totally depends on the performance of digest cycle within current app. $timeout will cause a digest. For an app with significant amount of watchers where `$rootScope.$digest()` makes the app freeze, it will freeze once more. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are some cases where one needs to perform some sort of timeout operation and we frequently achieve this using JavaScript's `setTimeout()` function.

However, if we use `setTimeout()` in an AngularJS application we also need to use `$scope.$apply()` to ensure that any changes to the `scope` will be reflected elsewhere (i.e. data-bound in a `view`).

`AngularJS` provides a handy wrapper for this: `$timeout()` - it does the `$apply()` for which we don't have to `$apply` the changes.

Regarding the **performance**.

If you're using `$timeout` to create what is essentially an interval, then don't use it. If your application is large then `$apply` will also trigger a `$digest` cycle which you may not really want it to happen, it will surely decrease the performance.

Answer (score 24):

Any AngularJS scope variable when handled from outside (including ajax) needs a $apply().

$timeout() takes care of the current scope and runs in the same digest cycle after all the change detection is done.

One beauty of $timeout() that I recently discovered is, if you do not pass the time parameter, it will wait for the DOM completion.

So,

```
$timeout(function(){
  console.log("show after directive partial loaded")
}); //note, no time parameter
```

Run this code in a directive and the timeout callback function will be fired once the partial has been loaded by the directive

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition, you can pass false as a second parameter to $timeout and it won't call an $apply. Useful when you want to control the $digest manually

Comment: The answer is vague on the details and possibly contains incorrect information. The statement on the directive usage is far-fetched and doesn't really explain how it differs from setTimeout+$scope.$apply. `$timeout(() => {... }, ...)` is essentially the same as `setTimeout(() => $scope.$apply(..), ...)`, except the fact that the former can be synchronously tested with `$timeout.flush()` (also, it has an option to skip the digest).