# $scope variable doesn't change in callback function, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, callback, ng-show

I want to show a spinner into button during function **one** running and after finishing, hide spinner, this is what I tried:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">       
        <button ng-click="InsertData()">

            <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>Loading
        </button>
        <br />
        {{loading}}
    </div>
```

and this is controller.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

$scope.InsertData=function()
{
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.one($scope.two);

}

$scope.one = function (callback) {

    setTimeout(function () { alert("this is function one"); callback(); }, 1000);

}

$scope.two = function () {
    alert("two");
    $scope.loading = false;

}

});
```

but this line

```
$scope.loading = false;
```

doesn't execute! although line above it runs, I mean alert("two") appears!

why the value of $scope.loading doesn't change in callback function? how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `setTimeout` which is a Javascript function, this will cause issues, where the scope variable will not be updated in the scope. Hence we must use the angular wrapper for this which is `$timeout()`.

More details [here](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout), to know the difference between `$timeout()` and `setTimeout()` refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310992/difference-between-settimeout-in-javascript-and-timeout-service-in-angularjs)

---

Below is a working fiddle for the question.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>